# variable length array declaration not allowed in OpenCL - why?

Tags: arrays, memory, memory-management, opencl, c99

I want to create a local array inside my OpenCL kernel, whose size depends on a parameter of the kernel. It seems that's not allowed - at least with AMD APP.

Is your experience different? Perhaps it's just the APP? Or is is there some rationale here?

**Edit:** I would now suggest variable length arrays should be allowed in CPU-side code too, and it was an unfortunate call by the C standard committee; but the question stands.

Answer (score 4):

You can dynamically allocate the size of a local block. You need to take it as a parameter to your kernel, and define its size when you call clSetKernelArg.

definition example:

```
__kernel void kernelName(__local float* myLocalFloats, ...)
```

host code:

```
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, myLocalFloatCount * sizeof(float), NULL); // <-- set the size to the correct number of bytes to allocate, but use NULL for the data.
```

Make sure you know what the limit for local memory is on your device before you do this. Call clGetDeviceInfo, and poll for the 'CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE' value.

Comment: This is the workaround I'm using, but - since this is possible, why should I not just be able to allocate a local array, either by declaring a variable-length array or calling some OpenCL malloc-like function?

Comment: I think it has to do with many of today's devices needing to know this information up front, so they can validate and allocate safely. I don't know yet of AMD's GCN architecture will support gpu-side malloc calls.

Comment: If that was allowed, then you should be able to dynamic allocate the device memory inside the kernel, return alloc errors, etc... And this is not possible in the GPU. At the kernel level everything needs to be static. As they said, the only way is to set it from the host code.

Comment: clSetKernelArg is called before clEnqueueNDRangeKernel, so it's not truly dynamic in the same sense. Maybe in the future the system will be more flexible for developers and memory management.

Comment: @DarkZeros: I said 'malloc-like', not 'malloc'... also, if we're talking about _local_ memory, and if we can assume only one kernel runs on a single multiprocessor at the same time, then - why should things be static? I should be able to be as dynamic as I want as long as it's not thread-level allocations

Comment: @mfa: It's no more dynamic than having a variable-length array declared at the beginning of the function. But - it's much less readable :-(

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why people are saying you can't do this as it is something many people do with OpenCL (Yes, I understand it's not exactly the same but it works well enough for many cases).

Since OpenCL kernels are compiled at runtime and, just like text, you can just simply set the size to whatever size you want and then recompile your kernel. This obviously won't be perfect in cases where you have huge variability in sizes but usually I compile several different sizes at startup and then just call the correct one as needed (in your case based on the kernel argument). If I get a new size I don't have a kernel for I will compile it right then and cache the kernel in case it comes up again.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, that does open up some interesting possibilities. Although, I must say I don't really understand why OpenCL kernels are compiled at run-time. If I can compile my host code in advance and assume it works, even though it might be hardware-specific (x86_64 vs x86 etc.), I don't see why the same shouldn't be the case for my GPU code. Anyway, you get your upvote...

Comment: I believe it is to have the flexibility to do these types of things when the hardware or driver can't. OpenCL is very nice to work with if you are looking for major performance gains with only moderate effort as well as hitting theoretical max when possible. (drivers are a bit of a headache but that's always an issue with these kinds of things and you figure out their quirks).

Comment: A given OpenCL runtime doesn't have to have a compiler though. There are a bunch of runtimes that can only execute ahead-of-time compiled kernels.