# How to set variable length array in OpenCl

Tags: opencl

In kernel parameters I have `int count`, to set length of array in kernel. But I get the following error

> variable length arrays are not supported in OpenCL.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995991/variable-length-array-declaration-not-allowed-in-opencl-why

Comment: @PPL, i have seen this. Thanks. I thought that there was another solution